# I get an errror (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'self') while trying to create an attribute of a class

Tags: python, pygame

```
class food:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw_food(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height. self.width))
        pygame.display.update()

    def collition_detection(self):
        pass



    pizza = food(random.randint(100,1000),random.randint(100,500) ,30, 30)
    pizza.draw_food()
```

When i run the above code, i get an attribute error saying (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'self') and i did exactly the same thing i did with other classes in my program and i am only having problem with this one class.

Comment: Your indentation is off; the code as shown shouldn't even run, because `food` is not defined inside the `class` statement that is defining `food`.

Comment: Further, *nothing* in this code tries to access an attribute named `self`, on an `int` object or otherwise.

Comment: I might have gotten the terminology wrong, appologies for that. I just want to draw the food on the screen and i have left 4 spaces while defining __init__  inside class.  Isn't it supposed to be 4?

Comment: There is a type `self.height, self.width` rather than `self.height. self.width`. Focus on `.` versus `,`

Comment: Ah, you just have a typo, as Rabbid76 pointed out

Comment: It says the error is specifically on line " pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height. self.width))"

Comment: You are passing a 3-tuple `(self.x, self.y, self.height.self.width)` (spacing adjusted to emphasize how your code is parsed), not a 4-tuple `(self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width)`.

Comment: AHH got it . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo: `self.height. self.width` instead of `self.height, self.width`. Focus on `.` versus `,`:

Replace

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height. self.width))`</s>

with

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))
```